# How does VB.NET 2008 round off integer numbers?

Tags: vb.net, variables, compiler-construction, integer, rounding

NOTE; I know about Math.Floor and Math.Round and stuff. That’s not what I’m looking for.

I would like to know how VB.NET 2008 internally handles the rounding off of integers.

For example:

```
    Test1 = (127 / 2) + 13
    Test2 = (127 / 2) + 12
```

Both test variables will give back 76, which seems strange to me.

```
(127 / 2) = 63.5
```

So

```
63.5 + 13 = 76.5

63.5 + 12 = 75.5
```

Since both have a .5 it seems logical to me that they either get rounded off to above or below. So expected answers are either:

```
Floor: 76,75 or Ceiling: 77,76
```

But instead it seems that 76.5 gets floored while 75.5 is upped.

Any clue on what rules VB.NET uses for this?

Comment: it is called bankers rounding; `x.5` values are rounded to the nearest even number to prevent a bias.  you can specify the mode using the Math.Round overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In vb.net, when I know I'll have a bunch of midpoints divisions like that one above (finding margin/padding on some layout control) I convert each part of the division by 2 to Integer before adding something else, like `CInt(127 / 2) + X`, not `CInt((127 / 2) + X)`. But that doesn't solve the whole thing, just fix it on some very specific cases though.